# Avoid compilation of unchanged sources using Makefile

Tags: c, shell, assembly, makefile

I've tried to write a Makefile which should by desire compile all sources into the objects and then build the output binary.

I've tried several examples and found the solution but only for if I put all sources in the same folder.

But in this project files are distributed across a multiple directories and sub-directories.

My modified Makefile looks as follows

```
TARGET=analyser
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
CFLAGS= -DNDEBUG -DCPU_MK64FN1M0VLL12 -DUSE_RTOS=1 -DPRINTF_ADVANCED_ENABLE=1 \
-DFRDM_K64F -DFREEDOM -DFSL_RTOS_FREE_RTOS -Os -Wall -fno-common \
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin \
-mthumb -mapcs -std=gnu99 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MMD -MP \
--specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -Wall -fno-common -ffunction-sections \
-fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mthumb -mapcs -Xlinker --gc-sections \
-Xlinker -static -Xlinker -z -Xlinker muldefs -Xlinker -Map=output.map -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Xlinker --defsym=__stack_size__=2048 -Xlinker \
--defsym=__heap_size__=25600 -Wall

LDSCRIPT=linker/MK64FN1M0xxx12_flash.ld

ASM_SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.S")
GCC_SOURCES := $(shell find . -name "*.c")

ASM_DIRNAME := $(shell dirname $(ASM_SOURCES))
GCC_DIRNAME := $(shell dirname $(GCC_SOURCES))

ASM_OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.S, $(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.o, $(ASM_SOURCES))
GCC_OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.c, $(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.o, $(GCC_SOURCES))

INCLUDES=\
    -Iapp/include \
    -ICMSIS \
    -Ifsl \
    -IFreeRTOS/include \
    -IFreeRTOS/include/private \
    -IFreeRTOS/src/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
    -Iinclude \
    -Idrivers/uart \
    -Idrivers/serial_manager \
    -Idrivers/lists \
    -Ilwip/port \
    -Ilwip/src \
    -Ilwip/src/include \

all:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(GCC_SOURCES) $(ASM_SOURCES) $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) -o $(TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCPY) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin -O binary

bad: $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)                  \
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) $^ -o $(TARGET) \

$(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.o:$(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.S               \
    $(GCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@        \

$(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.o:$(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.c               \
    $(GCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@        \

clean:
    rm $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET).d output.map
```

When I execute "make" command the compilation going through

But when I execute "make bad" I receive error

This is probably something simple for experienced coding experts, but I'm quite new in the Makefile world.

Can anyone help me how to figure this out?

The original Makefile before modifications looks as follows:

```
TARGET=analyser
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
CFLAGS= -DNDEBUG -DCPU_MK64FN1M0VLL12 -DUSE_RTOS=1 -DPRINTF_ADVANCED_ENABLE=1 \
-DFRDM_K64F -DFREEDOM -DFSL_RTOS_FREE_RTOS -Os -Wall -fno-common \
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin \
-mthumb -mapcs -std=gnu99 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MMD -MP \
--specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -Wall -fno-common -ffunction-sections \
-fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mthumb -mapcs -Xlinker --gc-sections \
-Xlinker -static -Xlinker -z -Xlinker muldefs -Xlinker -Map=output.map -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Xlinker --defsym=__stack_size__=2048 -Xlinker \
--defsym=__heap_size__=25600 -Wall

LDSCRIPT=linker/MK64FN1M0xxx12_flash.ld
SRCS=\
    startup/startup_MK64F12.S \
    startup/startup_MK64F12.c \
    app/network_analyser.c \
    app/config/pin_mux.c \
    app/config/board.c \
    app/config/clock_config.c \
    fsl/fsl_sim.c \
    fsl/fsl_clock.c \
    fsl/fsl_enet.c \
    fsl/fsl_ftfx_cache.c \
    fsl/fsl_ftfx_controller.c \
    fsl/fsl_ftfx_flash.c \
    fsl/fsl_ftfx_flexnvm.c \
    fsl/fsl_gpio.c \
    fsl/fsl_debug_console.c \
    fsl/fsl_str.c \
    fsl/fsl_uart.c \
    fsl/fsl_smc.c \
    fsl/fsl_common.c \
    fsl/fsl_assert.c \
    fsl/fsl_sbrk.c \
    fsl/fsl_phy.c \
    fsl/fsl_dspi.c \
    fsl/fsl_dspi_freertos.c \
    fsl/fsl_uart_freertos.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/portable/MemMang/heap_3.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/event_groups.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/list.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/queue.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/stream_buffer.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/tasks.c \
    FreeRTOS/src/timers.c \
    drivers/uart/uart_adapter.c \
    drivers/serial_manager/serial_manager.c \
    drivers/serial_manager/serial_port_uart.c \
    drivers/lists/generic_list.c \
    lwip/port/enet_ethernetif_kinetis.c \
    lwip/port/enet_ethernetif.c \
    lwip/port/sys_arch.c \
    lwip/src/api/api_lib.c \
    lwip/src/api/api_msg.c \
    lwip/src/api/err.c \
    lwip/src/api/if_api.c \
    lwip/src/api/netbuf.c \
    lwip/src/api/netdb.c \
    lwip/src/api/netifapi.c \
    lwip/src/api/sockets.c \
    lwip/src/api/tcpip.c \
    lwip/src/core/altcp.c \
    lwip/src/core/altcp_alloc.c \
    lwip/src/core/altcp_tcp.c \
    lwip/src/core/def.c \
    lwip/src/core/dns.c \
    lwip/src/core/inet_chksum.c \
    lwip/src/core/init.c \
    lwip/src/core/ip.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/autoip.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/dhcp.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/etharp.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/icmp.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/igmp.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip4.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip4_addr.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip4_frag.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/dhcp6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/ethip6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/icmp6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/inet6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6_addr.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/ip6_frag.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/mld6.c \
    lwip/src/core/ipv6/nd6.c \
    lwip/src/core/mem.c \
    lwip/src/core/memp.c \
    lwip/src/core/netif.c \
    lwip/src/core/pbuf.c \
    lwip/src/core/raw.c \
    lwip/src/core/stats.c \
    lwip/src/core/sys.c \
    lwip/src/core/tcp.c \
    lwip/src/core/tcp_in.c \
    lwip/src/core/tcp_out.c \
    lwip/src/core/timeouts.c \
    lwip/src/core/udp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/bridgeif.c \
    lwip/src/netif/bridgeif_fdb.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ethernet.c \
    lwip/src/netif/lowpan6.c \
    lwip/src/netif/lowpan6_ble.c \
    lwip/src/netif/lowpan6_common.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/auth.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/ccp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/chap-md5.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/chap-new.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/chap_ms.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/demand.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/eap.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/eui64.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/fsm.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/ipcp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/ipv6cp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/lcp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/lwip_ecp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/magic.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/mppe.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/multilink.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/ppp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/pppapi.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/pppcrypt.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/pppoe.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/pppol2tp.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/pppos.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/upap.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/utils.c \
    lwip/src/netif/ppp/vj.c \
    lwip/src/netif/slipif.c \
    lwip/src/netif/zepif.c \

INCLUDES=\
    -Iapp/include \
    -ICMSIS \
    -Ifsl \
    -IFreeRTOS/include \
    -IFreeRTOS/include/private \
    -IFreeRTOS/src/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
    -Iinclude \
    -Idrivers/uart \
    -Idrivers/serial_manager \
    -Idrivers/lists \
    -Ilwip/port \
    -Ilwip/src \
    -Ilwip/src/include \

all:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(SRCS) $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) -o $(TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCPY) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin -O binary

clean:
    rm $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET).d output.map
```

Comment: This can be done, but it would be much easier if you started with a very simple example: two or three subdirectories, half a dozen c source files, and a toy makefile to demonstrate the solution. Would that satisfy you? You can add the complications later.

Comment: The backslashes at the end of the rules (like `bad`) look strange. Please [edit] your question and show an example how your directory structure with source files looks like and where you want to have the resulting files. I suggest to add a target e.g. `help` that prints all variables `ASM_SOURCES` etc. Running `make -d` might also help to find out what `make` is searching for and what rules get executed.

Comment: @Bodo can you please take a look again at the original Makefile

Comment: @Bodo I've updated question with the original Makefile where I've used list of the source files

Comment: Your `CFLAGS` appear to contain a lot of link flags.  This can work, but it is more conventional to put link-specific flags (other than `-l` and maybe `-L`) in `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: I think I need to delete this question and post it again in a different form

Comment: There's no need to delete this question.  However, it would be a good idea to read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) — the same idea by a different name).  Your makefile is anything but minimal.  You might limit yourself to an example using 3 source files in each of 3 directories, with perhaps 3 directories containing headers, and with a much simpler set of C compiler options.  It would be easier to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone to participate with this task

The main problem was not only the syntax but also a TAB symbol generated by the "Sublime 3" software

I've changed my workspace to "vscode" and now I don't have any problems with unwanted TABs

Makefile is working

```
TARGET=analyser
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCPY=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
CFLAGS= -DNDEBUG -DCPU_MK64FN1M0VLL12 -DUSE_RTOS=1 -DPRINTF_ADVANCED_ENABLE=1 \
-DFRDM_K64F -DFREEDOM -DFSL_RTOS_FREE_RTOS -Os -Wall -fno-common \
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin \
-mthumb -mapcs -std=gnu99 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MMD -MP \
--specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -Wall -fno-common -ffunction-sections \
-fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mthumb -mapcs -Xlinker --gc-sections \
-Xlinker -static -Xlinker -z -Xlinker muldefs -Xlinker -Map=output.map -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Xlinker --defsym=__stack_size__=2048 -Xlinker \
--defsym=__heap_size__=25600 -Wall

LDSCRIPT=linker/MK64FN1M0xxx12_flash.ld

ASM_SOURCES = startup/startup_MK64F12.S
GCC_SOURCES = $(shell find . -name "*.c")

INCLUDES=\
    -Iapp \
    -ICMSIS \
    -Ifsl \
    -IFreeRTOS/include \
    -IFreeRTOS/include/private \
    -IFreeRTOS/src/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
    -Iinclude \
    -Idrivers/uart \
    -Idrivers/serial_manager \
    -Idrivers/lists \
    -Ilwip/port \
    -Ilwip/src \
    -Ilwip/src/include \

GCC_OBJECTS = $(GCC_SOURCES:.c=.o)
DEP_OBJECTS = $(GCC_SOURCES:.c=.d)

all: $(TARGET).bin

$(TARGET).bin: $(TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCPY) $< $@ -O binary

$(TARGET).elf: $(GCC_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(ASM_SOURCES) -T $(LDSCRIPT) $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -I $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET).d output.map $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(DEP_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Why take that nice explicit list of sources and replace it with `find`?  Bring back the list!

Especially why `find` for the *exactly one* assembly source?  Sure, splitting it from the C source files is probably a good move, but I see no advantage whatever to `find`ing it.

This ...

> ```
> ASM_DIRNAME := $(shell dirname $(ASM_SOURCES))
> ```

... is not useful (see below).

This ...

> ```
> GCC_DIRNAME := $(shell dirname $(GCC_SOURCES))
> ```

... is not only unuseful, but positively problemmatic.  Because you have multiple C sources, this variable will get a whole list of directory names, not just one.  And a bunch of duplicates, too, though that part isn't causing you a problem in practice.

These ...

> ```
> ASM_OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.S, $(ASM_DIRNAME)/%.o, $(ASM_SOURCES))
> GCC_OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.c, $(GCC_DIRNAME)/%.o, $(GCC_SOURCES))
> ```

... make frivolous and slightly wrong use of `$(patsubst)`.  Slightly wrong because the spaces after the commas are data, not delimiters.  Frivolous, because an ordinary substitution reference is clearer, shorter, more conventional, and and more portable for merely translating one filename extension to another.  There's some frivolity too in expressing the directory names explicitly instead of just including them in the `%`.  Recommended:

```
ASM_OBJECTS := $(ASM_SOURCES:.S=.o)
GCC_OBJECTS := $(GCC_SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

Your `all` target has no prerequisites and its recipe builds everything.  I realize that you carried this forward from the original makefile, but apparently you do not realize that this is the number one thing that needs to be revised to achieve your objective.  If you want to use an `all` target (it is a common convention, but not a necessity) then instead of a recipe, it should have all the top-level build outputs as prerequisites.  In your case, that appears to be only `$(TARGET).bin`.

As much as possible, each recipe should build the target of the recipe and nothing else of consequence.  By this principle, you should have separate rules for building `$(TARGET).bin` and `$(TARGET).elf`.

Every rule should express all of its target's prerequisites, so the rule for `$(TARGET).bin` should have `$(TARGET).elf` as a prerequisite, and the rule for `$(TARGET).elf` should have all the object files and perhaps also the linker script as prerequisites.

> But when I execute "make bad" I receive error

This is because the trailing backslashes in that rule make it invalid.  You *could* fix that by putting a semicolon (`;`) between the last prerequisite and the first backslash, but you *should* fix it by removing the backslashes and ensuring that the recipe is indented with a literal tab character (not spaces).

You should apply the same fix to your two pattern rules, too, for if you make some of the previously described changes correctly, then these will actually be used.  But you have also shot yourself in the foot with these by using the `$(GCC_DIRNAME)` and (a bit) the `$(ASM_DIRNAME)` variable.  You don't need these because the pattern stem will match directories just fine.  You don't want the former, because it makes your rule something along these lines:

```
dir1 dir1 dir2 dir3/%.o: dir1 dir1 dir2 dir3/%.c
        # ... recipe ...
```

There's all manner of things wrong with that, not least that it matches only some of the `.o` files you want to build.  Much simpler rules would do the the job better, something like:

```
%.o: %.S
        $(GCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
        $(GCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

If you renamed your `INCLUDES` to `CPPFLAGS` then you could even dump the latter rule altogether in favor of the built in one for compiling .c files.

Additionally, your `clean` target does not clean the object files, and you ought to declare targets phony if their rules do not actually build files with the target name.

Overall, then, my recommendedation would take this form:

```
TARGET = analyser
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
CFLAGS = # flags ...

LDSCRIPT = linker/MK64FN1M0xxx12_flash.ld
ASM_SOURCES = startup/startup_MK64F12.S
GCC_SOURCES = \
  # long/list/of/sources.c ... \
  # last/source.c

ASM_OBJECTS = $(ASM_SOURCES:.S=.o)
GCC_OBJECTS = $(GCC_SOURCES:.c=.o)

CPPFLAGS = \
  # -Ithe/includes ... \
  # -Ilast/include

all: $(TARGET).bin

$(TARGET).bin: $(TARGET).elf
        $(OBJCPY) $< $@ -O binary

$(TARGET).elf: $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) $^

%.o: %.S
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin $(TARGET).d output.map $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made some improvements to my script, didn't solve the problem completely as I originally wanted to replace big list of source files and include folders with Makefile commands, but figured I could use some external scripts to perform this

Comment: Well, @IceDefcon, if that's what you wanted then you should have said so.  But as this answer expresses, I think it's preferable to not do that.  Makefiles should, IMO, *explicitly* specify the details of what is to be built.

Answer (score 3):

Your `all:` rules says "compile everything every time":

```
all:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(GCC_SOURCES) $(ASM_SOURCES) $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) -o $(TARGET).elf
    $(OBJCPY) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin -O binary
```

If the file `all` doesn't exist, then run the C compiler on all the sources and create the executable (but not the file `all`).  If the file `all` exists, nothing happens — `all` doesn't depend on anything.

If you don't want to compile everything, you'll need to tell `make` that the executable depends on the object files and link the object files.

I think you need something more like:

```
PROGRAM = $(TARGET).elf

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(GCC_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) -o $(PROGRAM)
    $(OBJCPY) $(PROGRAM) $(TARGET).bin -O binary
```

You may have to do some work to get the object files built, but this says "`all` depends on the program, and the program depends on the object files, and when the object files are all up to date, you build the program like this".  You might want to designate `.PHONY: all` as it isn't a 'real' target — it isn't a file that you create.

You should use macros for repeating elements like `PROGRAM = $(TARGET).elf` (and probably `$(TARGET).bin` too).  If you have to write it out more than once, it should probably be a macro.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made some improvements to my script, didn't solve the problem completely as I originally wanted to replace big list of source files and include folders with Makefile commands, but figured I could use some external scripts to perform this